# Plotting two sets of data points on funnel plot (metafor for R)

Tags: r

I am performing a meta-analysis of epidemiological data where studies can be segregated into two groups (e.g. by methodology). Is there any way to alter the points plotted on the funnel plot to identify the groups (e.g. dots and crosses)?
(Much as the pch.fill does when trimfill is used) 
Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about the funnel() command? It accepts pch option. See page 81 of the [technical document](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/metafor/metafor.pdf).

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't as clear as I should've been. I want to plot two separate groups of points on the same funnel (from the same meta-analysis). Each group represents a subgroup within the analysis. How can I change the points plotted to represent the groups differently? pch would seem to change all the points plotted, thanks

Comment: For each study, there should be an indicator showing if it's method A of method B, right? Suppose the variable is called StudyType (= 1 if method A, = 2 if method B), you can then plot them with different symbol by specifying "pch=StudyType." The plot will use pch=1 for TypeA, and pch=2 for TypeB.

Answer (score 3):

For each study, there should be an indicator showing if it's method A of method B, right? Suppose the variable is called StudyType (= 16 if method A, = 17 if method B), you can then plot them with different symbol by specifying "pch=StudyType." The plot will use pch=16 for TypeA, and pch=17 for TypeB.

```
### load BCG vaccine data
data(dat.bcg)

### Attach study type (I just randomly made up some here):
StudyType = sample(c(16,17),13,replace=T)

### meta-analysis of the log relative risks using a random-effects model
res <- rma(ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg,
           data=dat.bcg, measure="RR", method="REML")

### standard funnel plot (Notice the pcd command)
funnel(res, pch=StudyType)
```

[image]